# Install GNUPG on xampp windows

Tags: php, apache, xampp, gnupg, openpgp

I want to use PGP in my PHP project, using XAMPP on Windows.

When I run this code:

```php
$public_key = "PGP Public Key";
$gpg = new gnupg();
$key = $gpg->import($public_key);
$gpg->addencryptkey($key['fingerprint']);
$enc = $gpg->encrypt("Hello Stackoverflow!");
$gpg->clearencryptkeys();
echo nl2br($enc);
```

I get an error message telling me that I have to install the GNUPG extension in my Apache server.

How do I install GNUPG for XAMPP on Windows? I only found solutions for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official [php-gnupg](https://github.com/php-gnupg/php-gnupg) repository, there's no extension for Windows yet.

> The extension is not currently supported on Windows due to unavailable GpgME library builds that would be supported by PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `libgpgme-11.dll, php_gnupg.dll, libgpg-error.dll`

Extensions pack to your `php.ini` configuration file

https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html

Comment: Where are the .dll files for Windows?

Comment: @Sam_Benne - Were you able to find any information deeper into the DLL or getting this setup on XAMPP?